# NavigationView , App:Menu Cambiar tamaño de Letra

Tags: java, android

Tengo un menú en android studio , el cual no puedo modificar el tamaño del texto del mismo , aquí mi código

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    />

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/INICIO"
        android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
        android:title="Inicio"

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/BeneficiariosPreDefinidos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
        android:title="Beneficiarios Pre - Definidos"
       />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/VincularCuentasBilletera"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
        android:title="Vincular Cuentas a Billetera"
       />
    <item

        android:id="@+id/MovimientosBilletera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
        android:title="Movimientos de Billetera"
       />

</group>

<item android:title="Perfil">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
            android:title="Información Personal" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
            android:title="Cambiar Correo" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/das"
            android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
            android:title="Cambiar contraseña" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="">
</item>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:id="@+id/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    android:icon="@drawable/ssddqq"
    android:title="Salir" />
</group>
```

no me funciona el android:TextSize

Intente ponerle un style con   `android:theme="@style/Menu"` :

```
<style name="Menu" parent="zxing_CaptureTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
</style>
```

pero nada funciona como puedo cambiar el tamaño gracias

foto del menu [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">19dp</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="Menu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente debe funcionar agregando un tema con un tamaño de texto distinto como ya lo estas realizando, el problema es que no es:

```
android:theme="@style/Menu"
```

debe ser:

```
app:theme="@style/Menu"
```

este tema definelo en el layout de tu `NavigationView`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"

    app:theme="@style/Menu"
    />
```

---

Como ejemplo defino 2 temas:

```
<style name="MenuA" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">29dp</item>
</style>
```

Al definir en el NavigationView el tema con el estilo que define `android:textSize = 9dp` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"

    app:theme="@style/MenuA"/>
```

se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

definiendo el estilo que define `android:textSize = 29dp`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"

    app:theme="@style/MenuB"/>
```

se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ah valla ya lo intentare así entonces Jorge agradezco muchísimo la mano que me das  , lo pruebo y si queda funcionando te tildo como respuesta Aceptada

Comment: Cual es el thema que usa tu aplicación? puedes agregarlo, veo que estas usando parent="zxing_CaptureTheme" , cambia al que usa tu aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por responder de verdad agradezco que te tomes estos minutos para darme ejemplos tan claros lo revisare y te comento ,

Comment: en mi manifest tengo esto

Comment: <application
        android:name=".Globals"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mm_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

Comment: no me deja escribirle otro theme

Comment: No modifiques nada dentro del Manifest.xml, agrega tu archivo styles.xml

Comment: Esta editada mi publicacion con el styles.xml

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65257/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-navigationview-appmenu-cambiar-tamano-de-let).

Answer (score 0):

Ami me funciono usando lo siguiente,
en vez de usar esto:

```
  app:theme="@style/MenuB"
```

use esto

```
 app:itemTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowStyle"
```

Dentro del navigationView tengo el siguiente código:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_menu"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowStyle"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemIconSize="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Verdeapejal">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Y en el tema (esto es en los temas no en el manifiest) tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">29dp</item>
    </style>
```

[image: Evidencia del funcionamiento del estilo]

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede ayudar a solucionar el problema, es crucial que expliques por qué, y cómo funciona el código. Si un usuario sin experiencia ve el código y simplemente lo copia y lo pega sin entenderlo, esto socava el verdadero aprendizaje.